# What does __flags__ in python type used for

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle, cpython

I have been read pickle source code recently.

The following code in `copy_reg` make me confused:

```
_HEAPTYPE = 1<<9

def _reduce_ex(self, proto):
    assert proto < 2
    for base in self.__class__.__mro__:
        if hasattr(base, '__flags__') and not base.__flags__ & _HEAPTYPE:
            break
    else:
        base = object # not really reachable
    if base is object:
        state = None
```

So what does `__flags__` using for?

I found it is defined in `type` object:

```
type.__flags__ = 2148423147
```

I was tried to search it in the official doc, but nothing was found.

But interesting thing is that `__class__.__flags__ & _HEAPTYPE` is always `0` when the `__class__` is python internal type. And the result will be `1` when `__class__` is a subclass of python internal type.

Can anyone help me to solve this puzzle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__flags__` is a wrapper, [to access CPython type object structure member `tp_flags`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Objects/typeobject.c#L340-L351), constants used to compose this flag [defined in object.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Include/object.h#L596-L661), following is quoted from the source:

> Type flags (tp_flags)
>   These flags are used to extend the type structure in a backwards-compatible
>   fashion. Extensions can use the flags to indicate (and test) when a given
>   type structure contains a new feature. The Python core will use these when
>   introducing new functionality between major revisions (to avoid mid-version
>   changes in the PYTHON_API_VERSION).

See more detail on [python document on `tp_flags`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_flags).

> But interesting thing is that **class**.**flags** & _HEAPTYPE is always 0 when the **class** is a python internal type. And the result will be 1 when **class** is a subclass of python internal type.

Subclass of python built-in type, like other user defined type, allocated on heap with `PyType_GenericAlloc()`.

---

to break down `type.__flags__`:

```
import re

def flags_to_name(type_obj):
    tp_flag_consts = {}        
    with open('/path/to/Include/object.h') as f:
        for l in f:
            m = re.search(r'^#define (Py_TPFLAGS_\w+)\s+\(.+?<< (\d+)\)', l.strip())
            if m:
                tp_flag_consts[int(m.group(2))] = m.group(1)
    bin_str = bin(type_obj.__flags__)[2:][::-1]
    return ', '.join(tp_flag_consts[n] for n, c in enumerate(bin_str) if c == '1')

print(flags_to_name(type))
```

yields:

```
Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE, Py_TPFLAGS_READY, Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_GC, Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_VERSION_TAG, Py_TPFLAGS_VALID_VERSION_TAG, Py_TPFLAGS_TYPE_SUBCLASS
```

Answer (score 2):

`__flags__` is to be viewed as binary, if you want to see the flags.

These type flags are defined [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/31a8393cf6a74c870c3484dd68500619f6232c6d/Include/object.h#L598) in Python's source code.