# Understanding object.__flags__ and ndarray.__flags__

Tags: python, numpy, oop, multidimensional-array

What does the result from `object.__flags__` mean? And how to interpret it?

```
In [55]: str.__flags__
Out[55]: 269227008

In [56]: list.__flags__
Out[56]: 34362368

In [57]: tuple.__flags__
Out[57]: 67916800

In [58]: object.__flags__
Out[58]: 791552

In [59]: ndarray.__flags__
Out[59]: 791552
```

Also, most importantly, why do we get the same result for `object.__flags__` and `ndarray.__flags__` ?

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47633511/289011) Maybe you'll find it interesting? (I personally didn't know anything about this `__flags__` thingy until I read your question)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \_\_flags\_\_ in python type used for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47633511/what-does-flags-in-python-type-used-for)

Comment: That answer really answers your question if you read it carefully. You can find there is an `Include/object.h` file which contains corresponding masks. To find out what does `791552` mean and why `ndarray` and `object` have the same `__flags__`, you just need to make a little efforts to figure out what is the corresponding masks of `791552`.

Comment: Evidently for the purposes that the interpreter uses the flags bits (garbage collection, subclassing, etc), an `ndarray` has the same properties as the base `object` class.  Defining a class with `Class ...:` sets a different value (that includes subclasses of `ndarray`).

Comment: I've deduced from `numpy` `src` code that `ndarray` flags are set as `Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE`, `0b11000001010000000000`.  That's true for dtypes as well.  `np.ufunc` is just `DEFAULT` (it can't be subclassed). Builtins like `list` have added bits above 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the linked SO: [What does __flags__ in python type used for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47633511/what-does-flags-in-python-type-used-for)

and 
[object.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/31a8393cf6a74c870c3484dd68500619f6232c6d/Include/object.h#L598)

it is evident that `__flags__` is the integer representation of the `tpflags` attribute of a class.  Displayed as binary, your examples are:

```
In [165]: "{0:29b}".format(str.__flags__)     # high bit (1UL << 28)
Out[165]: '10000000011000001010000000000'
In [166]: "{0:29b}".format(tuple.__flags__)   # (1UL << 26)
Out[166]: '  100000011000101010000000000'
In [167]: "{0:29b}".format(list.__flags__)   # (1UL << 25)
Out[167]: '   10000011000101010000000000'
```

`object` doesn't have these high specialized bits:

```
In [168]: "{0:29b}".format(object.__flags__)
Out[168]: '         11000001010000000000'
In [169]: "{0:29b}".format(np.ndarray.__flags__)
Out[169]: '         11000001010000000000'
In [171]: "{0:29b}".format(1<<10 | 1<<12 | 1<<18 | 1<<19)
Out[171]: '         11000001010000000000'
```

`np.ufunc` does not have the `1<<10` bit, `Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE`.

```
In [170]: "{0:29b}".format(np.ufunc.__flags__)
Out[170]: '         11000001000000000000'
```

I can't subclass it:

```
In [173]: class foo(np.ufunc):
     ...:     pass
TypeError: type 'numpy.ufunc' is not an acceptable base type
```

Flags for a user defined class are

```
In [176]: class Foo:
     ...:     pass
In [177]: "{0:29b}".format(Foo.__flags__)
Out[177]: '         11000101011000000001'
```

That's also true for subclasses of `np.ndarray` such as `np.matrix`.

We can search the numpy code for `tpflags` definitions

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tpflags&type=

In `arrayobject.c`, flags are set to `Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE`.  In `ufunc_object.c` just `Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT`.

In sum, `__flags__` show that `np.ndarray` is an ordinary base class. `numpy` does not try to set any special properties with this attribute.